# Another espresso.AppNotIdleException api 28-29 only

Tags: android, android-espresso

This problem only appears on API 28 and 29 (27, 30, 31 work fine).

I have a very basic test to check application start:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
class MainActivityTest {
    @Test
    fun mainActivityInView() {
        val activityScenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)
        onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
}
```

I'm using navigation component and single activity pattern. Here is some xmls:

Main Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_main"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
    
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ScienceTracker.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.ScienceTracker.PopupOverlay" >
            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_favorite_btn"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:background="@drawable/button_favorite"
                android:text=""
                android:textOff=""
                android:textOn=""
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

For the sake of the test, I created a new empty fragment and set it to "home", so that the contents of the fragment do not affect the result in any way.

There are no progress bars.

Animations are disabled in emulator settings.

I checked the update of the main thread through the display setting in the developer menu.

Gradle:

```
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0"

    // androidx.test
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:1.4.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.4.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.3"
```

Any ideas?